# connect jasperreports to ms access database using ucanaccess

Tags: ms-access-2013, netbeans-8, ucanaccess, jasper-plugin

I use UcanAccess to access MS Access database from java 8 u 02 ,I want to configure jaspereports plugin on netbeans to connect to a MDB Database using UcanAccess ,I know that JdbcOdbc Driver is not supproted on java 8 , SO Any idea of How I Procced ?

SO After searching ,I have found some method of adding five jar file of ucanaccess on ireport plugin classpath but I get this error :
[IMAGE001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hybP5.png)

the five jar file are  added correctlly : [IMAGE002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKI6k.png)